# Redirect to another controller, if and only if, a condition is met. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code that is activated every time I navigate from one view to another in my application.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, auth,$state)
{
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event,url){ 
  //exist token, redirect to home
  if(auth.checkStatus()){

    $state.go("home");

  }
  else{
    //not exists token, stop redirection, go to /
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go("/");
  }
 })
})
```

If I have a token in localstorage, there is no restriction to redirect any state. But if the token does not exist in the localstorage, then I should not load another template, and redirect to the "/" state. The problem I have is when the token is not defined, it redirects well to the "/" state, but it also loads the template and redirect to which it is going. I need only load another template only if the token is defined.

```
//factory auth
  oLogin.checkStatus= function()
    {

        var aRutasPrivadas = [];
        var aRutas=$state.get(); //get array with all the states
        for(var i in aRutas)
        {
            aRutasPrivadas.push(aRutas[i].url); 
        }

        if(this.in_array($location.path(),aRutasPrivadas) &&  (window.localStorage.getItem("TOKEN") === null || window.localStorage.getItem("TOKEN") === undefined) )
        {

           return false;
        }
        else{
          return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the transition from happening.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for replying, but where do I do it ?, if I put event.preventDefault (), it will not be redirected to another state later.

Comment: right, so you need more logic to see if `checkStatus` is true or not and if you are trying to access home or not

Comment: @charlietfl At the moment I am in my house, I can try it in about an hour, but I have updated the code. Taking advantage of your kindness, and that you are in this moment, with this would solve my problem ?. Thank you.

Comment: @charlietfl it not works for me..